# Exception: "Cannot locate resource 'FilePath.xaml'" when path contains square brackets and using dot net 4.5

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.5

We have a C# application with some screens written in WPF. I am trying to migrate it to dot net framework 4.5 (I need to use one of it's features). But when I run my application I am getting an exception that comes from WPF code.

I have researched it for a while and come to conclusion that the problem is with the square brackets in the XAML file path (we use this convention when it should not appear in the class namespace).

I have created a simple WPF test application. Added new folder named: [newfolder1] (with the brackets) to the solution. Moved the window to that folder and when I run it I am getting the following error:
Cannot locate resource '[newfolder1]/mainwindow.xaml'.

If I remove the brackets from the folder it's working well.

I didn't find any reference to this issue on the net, this makes me think that I am doing something wrong. My last resort is to remove the brackets from the folders names though this will require a lot of effort.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.